# Magento: add message to add to cart Ajax button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I want to add a message in a div for say 5 seconds,

"Product added to cart" on screen.

As presently, when clicking on the button the product is simply added to the cart, but no message is displayed the product is added to the cart, which for some customers is not clear, whether the product is added.

```
The relevant Magento code for add to card is like this:

<div class="add-to-cart-buttons -field -field-actions -clearfix">
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" 
class="button btn-cart -button -button-wide add-to-bag -button-fancy"
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>
<?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?></div>
```

update: related Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var ajaxRequest = true;
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
               if(ajaxRequest) { 
                    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl('sischeckout/cart/add'); ?>',{
                        method: "POST",
                        parameters:form.serialize(),
                        onSuccess: function(transport) {
                            try{ 

                           data = JSON.parse(transport.responseText); 

                                }catch(e){ data = {};
                            } 
                            if(!data.status) {
                                 alert(data.message); 

                            } 
                        }, 
                        onFailure: function(transport) {
                            alert('Invalid Request'); 
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    var e = null;
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                    } catch (e) {
                    }

                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                } 
            } else {
                    if(ajaxRequest) {
                        alert("Product options are required field.");
                    }
                }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: you could look for `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` function and rewrite it for adding message

Comment: is it not possible to add a message here itself? Not much idea about jQuery, javascript.

Comment: i don't know even what code is using for adding product to the cart. You just show simple code for buttons markup )

Comment: @kRicha - updated some relevant code. does that makes sense.

Comment: Have you installed any ajax add to cart extension in your site?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Magento give message when you add products in to cart. There are two types of settings are available in Magento.

1. When customer add product in cart then it will redirect to cart page and display message that your product added in cart.
2. When customer add product the cart then it will stay on same page and display message that your product added in cart.

So you have to check why Magento's default message is not display when customer add product in to cart in your site.

Answer (score 0):

For showing message, Please Replace the code

```
onSuccess: function(transport) {
                            try{ 

                           data = JSON.parse(transport.responseText); 
                            jQuery(.cart .page-title).after("<ul class="messages"><li class="success-msg"><ul><li><span>Product was added to your shopping      cart.</span></li></ul></li></ul>");
                                }catch(e){ data = {};
                            } 
                            if(!data.status) {
                                 alert(data.message); 

                            } 
                        }
```

To

```
onSuccess: function(transport) {
                            try{ 

                           data = JSON.parse(transport.responseText); 
                           jQuery(".cart > .page-title").after("<ul class='messages'><li class='success-msg'><ul><li><span>Product was added to your shopping       cart.</span></li></ul></li></ul>");
                                }catch(e){ data = {};
                            } 
                            if(!data.status) {
                                 alert(data.message); 

                            } 
                        }
```